# Duplicate row with inner join

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm Using inner join query for fetch data from two table.

My query like below:-

```
Select * From tbl_note n  inner join tbl_tag_note_join t on n.n_id=t.n_id WHERE t.tag_id IN (2,3)  ORDER BY n.n_id DESC
```

I'm getting duplicate rows in output Please help i don't know what problem with my query.

My output is below:-

[image]

Comment: looks like your join keys are not complete, are you sure that they ensure uniqueness

Comment: The rows are *not* duplicates; the values in the `tag_id` column are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i'm Using below query with `group by` i find solution and remove duplicate record.

Final query is like below:-

```
Select * From tbl_note n inner join tbl_tag_note_join t on n.n_id=t.n_id WHERE t.tag_id IN (2,3) GROUP by n.n_id ORDER BY n.n_id DESC
```